# React Native Pass not custom props to children

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native. At the moment I'm trying to create a component which is similar to the `TextInput`. I want to be able to pass all props, that `TextInput` offers. The parent (the custom component) should pass them to the `TextInput` (in the returned jsx). This works fine with `...props` but since I'm using a custom props, it seems to break this method. Here's my code (it is truncated):

```
function StateTextInput(props){
    const
        [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""),
        valueHandler = given => {
            props.valueHandler(given); // That's the custom prop
        };

    return (
        <TextInput
            {...props}
            value={inputValue}
            style={[styles.input, props.style]}
        />
    )
}

export default StateTextInput;
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<StateTextInput
    valueHandler={value => {
        return value.toString().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    }}
/>

<StateTextInput
    valueHandler={value => {
        return value.toString().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    }}
    placeholder="Test" // Prop from TextInput!
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `console.log(props.valueHandler)` before your custom-component `return (...)` you should see that it is set properly. Unless you truncated more than you meant to, based on the code above the reason `valueHandler` is not getting called is because your TextInput doesn't actually have the required `onChangeText` attribute to call it.

Comment: The problem is, that `valueHandler` is not a prop of `TextInput`. I get this error: `React does not recognize the `valueHandler` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `valuehandler` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.`. How do I remove the prop before inserting it using `{...props}` (in my `TextInput`)?

Comment: Destructuring is an excellent way. If you use the code `const { valueHandler, ...otherProps } = props` you will have `valueHandler` as its own variable to use in your callback, and `otherProps` will contain everything EXCEPT `valueHandler`.